# How to make viewport resizable and trigger the onResize event in XPages Mobile Controls?

Tags: xpages

I am trying to code the onResize event new in release 9.0.1 but am failing to trigger this event.  I added a metedata resource to override the default but not sure its taking effect.

Here's the complete Xsp source for my test XPage ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
   <xp:this.resources>
       <xp:metaData name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=yes">
      </xp:metaData>
   </xp:this.resources>
   <xe:singlePageApp id="singlePageApp1" selectedPageName="home">
       <xe:appPage id="appPage1" pageName="home">
           <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading1" label="Resize Test"></xe:djxmHeading>
        <xp:panel>
            <p> Bacon ipsum dolor amet shankle doner drumstick, pork
            tail kevin sirloin pork belly beef picanha turducken
            pancetta porchetta. Bacon meatloaf turducken brisket
            meatball drumstick kielbasa venison pastrami filet
            mignon rump sirloin. 
            </p>
            <p>Porchetta frankfurter biltong,
            t-bone tri-tip ribeye filet mignon ham pastrami cow
            kielbasa boudin. Salami pork loin strip steak beef
            hamburger pancetta sausage beef ribs frankfurter filet
            mignon spare ribs meatloaf. 
            </p>
        </xp:panel>
       </xe:appPage>
       <xp:eventHandler event="onResize" submit="false">
          <xe:this.script><![CDATA[alert("onResize triggered");]]></xe:this.script>
       </xp:eventHandler></xe:singlePageApp>
</xp:view>
```

The following are the meta tags when I view the source for the rendered page.  It does shows my viewport meta tag after the default, but not sure that means my viewport settings are in effect.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=yes">
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the viewport is set in the theme. You also can't have 2 of the statements. The specification is open about what happens (ignore, error, 1st wins, seconds wins).

Best: create your own theme, base it on the theme you had initially selected and change add your entry. It then should reduce the viewport entries to one.

Let us know how it works

Comment: Thanks Stephan, that worked for me when in my theme I extend the OneUI IDX theme, as in <theme extends="oneui_idx_v1.3" ... >  However not sure how to extend the default mobile theme.  I tried <theme extends="mobile" ... > and <theme extends="default" ... > but neither of those worked for me.